# PHP to fill link from an HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been around PHP for a while but I cant' wrap my head around how to get this working.

Very simple- I want my link to fill an HTTP link dynamically depending on what happened depending on what was inputted into my form.

So I simply want this HTTP link to fill dynamically (as the user's phone number will need to be inserted, and my API key will need to be hidden).

My HTML

```
<form>
<label for="Name">Phone Number</label><br>
<input type="SMSnumber" id="name" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send me the SMS">
```

PHP to fill link:

```
https://api.clockworksms.com/http/send.aspx?key=APIKEY&to=<?php echo $_POST["SMSnumber"]; 
?>&content=Hello+World
```

(original link https://api.clockworksms.com/http/send.aspx?key=KEY&to=441234567890&content=Hello+World)

I need to tell my PHP to fill in the  section which is inputted in the form (label "SMSnumber"). I think that may work but it still leaves my API key exposed in HTML.

How can I tell this link to happen when the "submit" button is clicked?

How can I hide the link itself so my API is not visible to the public?

Thanks

Comment: you do not tell us where you use that link, if you send the data with the PHP to that URL then the API key is not exposed, you can use cURL Library http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php for server to server communication

Comment: I plan to share the link on my home page (publiclly) for users to enter their number in order to be SMS'd a link to the AppStore.

Comment: You can't protect your API key if you set it at your homepage, you must let the users post the data you want them to post and then handle at your server the request and direct the data to the Link with your API key.

Comment: So general what you need to do is, create a form that users will submit the SMSnumber to your script then create the URL in the backend and send the data to that URL via cURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the HTTP method. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

```
<form method="POST">
//------^
```

To hide your api key you can do the following. by using [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Ofcourse you have to add your API-key in the code below.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['SMSnumber'])){
    $url = 'https://api.clockworksms.com/http/send.aspx?key=APIKEY&to=' . $_POST["SMSnumber"] . '&content=Hello+World';

    $ch = curl_init();

        //Set Options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        // Execute request
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        echo $result;

} else {

?>

<form method="POST">
<label for="Name">Phone Number</label><br>
<input name="SMSnumber" type="text" id="name" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send me the SMS">
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks- but that shows the link publically. How can I keep it private? And how can I get that link to run when "submit" is clicked?

Comment: Edited my asnwer, you can grab the course code of your api with Curl. With the source code you can do what ever you want. Its stored in $result

Comment: Thanks- but the "Submit" button takes me to a "test.php" page, and doesn't seem to actually 'execute' the HTTP request.

Comment: I removed action="test.php" and it worked. Thank you Dr Phil

Comment: Ow sorry `action="test.php"` shouldn't be there, that was for testing it here. edited my answer.

Comment: Is there a nice way to return my API responses? Right now they're a bit ugly (http://www.clockworksms.com/doc/easy-stuff/http-interface/send-sms/)

Comment: It's hard to tell, What does a response looks like? I guess it looks something like "To: 441234567890 ID: AB_12345" just a normal string

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose your API key then the request must be sent from the backend like this:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['SMSnumber']){
    $url="https://api.clockworksms.com/http/send.aspx?key=APIKEY&to=".$_POST["SMSnumber"]."&content=Hello+World";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
         CURLOPT_URL => $url,
         CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3'
       ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
  }
?>
<form method="POST">
 <label for="Name">Phone Number</label><br>
 <input type="text" name='SMSnumber' id="name" required><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send me the SMS">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `form` to

```
<form method="post">
<label for="Name">Phone Number</label><br>
<input name="SMSnumber" type="text" id="name" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send me the SMS">
</form>
```

Because You used `<?php echo $_POST["SMSnumber"]; ?>` to this `name` attribute of `input` should be `SMSnumber`